# iPhone : Validation fileExistsAtPath

Tags: iphone, validation, store, detect, cydia

In my app I want to detect if "Cydia" is installed on the device,
so I use:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:@"/Applications/Cydia.app"]).
```

It seems to work but I wonder if Apple will validate it or not.
Does anybody have an application in the appStore that uses this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go ahead with this or you can register a custom URL scheme for your Cydia application and then call `canOpenURL` in your current application to detect if the application is installed.

Comment: I don't have any Cydia application. I'm developing an app for the appStore and just want to know if the user have a jailbroken iDevice (so "Cydia" installed)